# Retrieve particular fields from mongomapper using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As per documentation "http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#fields" I am using the following code to retrieve "file_size" from Image table:

```
Image.where(:user_id => "#{self.id}").fields(:file_size).all
```

But its fetching all the fields from Image table.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Image.fields(:file_size).all.to_json(:only => :file_size)
```